# How to calculate percentile in Java without using Library

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate `95th Percentile` from the data sets which I have populated in my below `ConcurrentHashMap`.

**I am interested in finding out how many calls came back in 95th percentile of time**

My Map will look like this and it will always be sorted in ascending order on the keys- In which

```
key - means number of milliseconds
value - means number of calls that took that much milliseconds


Milliseconds    Number

0               1702
1               15036
2               14262
3               13190
4               9137
5               5635
6               3742
7               2628
8               1899
9               1298
10              963
11              727
12              503
13              415
14              311
15              235
16              204
17              140
18              109
19              83
20              72
```

For example, from the above data sets, it means

> 1702 calls came back in 0 milliseconds
>
> 15036 calls came back in 1 milliseconds

Now I can calculate the 95th percentile by plugging the above data sets in the `Excel sheet`. But I was thinking to calculate the percentile in Java code.

I know the algorithm will look something like this-

Sum all values from the map, calculate 95% of the sum, iterate the map keys in ascending order keeping a running total of values, and when sum equals or exceeds the previously calculated 95% of the total sum, the key should be the 95th percentile I guess.

But I am not able to plugin this algorithm in the Java code. Below is the map which will have above datasets.

```
Map<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>
```

I am not sure what is the best way to calculate the percentile in Java. I am not sure whether I am algorithm is also correct or not. I am just trying to find out how many calls came back in 95th percentile of time.

```
private static void calculatePercentile() {

    for (Long time : CassandraTimer.histogram.keySet()) {

    
    }

}
```

Can anyone provide some example how to do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

**Updated code:-**

Below is the code I have got so far. Let me know if I got everything correct in calculating the 95th percentile-

```
/**
 * A simple method to log 95th percentile information
 */
private static void logPercentileInfo() {

    double total = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : CassandraTimer.histogram.entrySet()) {
        long value = entry.getKey() * entry.getValue();
        total += value;
    }

    double sum = 0.95*total;

    double totalSum = 0;

    SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(CassandraTimer.histogram.keySet());
    for (long key : keys) {

        totalSum += CassandraTimer.histogram.get(key);

        if(totalSum >= sum) {
           //this is the 95th percentile I guess
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sum the total time and get the number in which the `.95/total` time came in from

Comment: @ratchet freak. Thanks for the suggestion. It will be great if you can provide an example for me? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why a `ConcurrentHashMap`?  You might want to look at the `ConcurrentSkipListMap` or `TreeMap` which implement `SortedMap` so that you get the numbers out in order (if order is important).  Though noting that the structure is integers from 0-20, you may just want an array without the overhead of the map.

Comment: @MichaelT Oops I pasted wrong code. I have updated the code which is using `SortedMap`. Can you please take a look and let me know whether I am calculating the percentile correctly or not for my problem?

Comment: How does it compare to your excel run?

Comment: I haven't ran my program yet. As my database is down currently so I cannot run it and compare it. That is the reason I wanted to make sure, I am doign right or not

Comment: You have the data set that you quoted above that you can plug into your code and excel...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but
it's easy to get a percentile. Suppose you have 100 numbers. You sort them and extract the 95th one (if you want the 95th percentile). If you don't have a multiple of 100 numbers you may have to do some interpolation. I assume you know how to do that.

EDIT: OK, you already have the numbers in order. First get the total of the column called "Number". Call that Tot. Then enumerate through them, keeping a running sum of the column and call that RS. When RS passes 0.95 * Tot, you've found it. As I said, you might want to do some interpolation so you get a fractional number of milliseconds.

Your question has the right idea. It's not a big deal.

```
for (i=0, sum=0; i<n; i++) sum += Number[i];
tot = sum;
for (i=0, sum=0; i<n && sum < 0.95*tot; i++) sum += Number[i];
// i is about it
```

Comment: I have a very simple use case. In my question above, I am just trying to see how many calls came back in 95th percentile of time. For example- 95th percentile of time calls came back in `5 ms`, something like this. So that is the reason I have my data in the map. I believe I know the algorithm but I am not able to put together in the java code. If you can provide me an example then I can learn something from that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It kind of make sense. But I am having hard time in putting this to actual code. That is the reason I ask any example can make me better understand this. if you can provide me an example then that will be of great help.

Comment: @user21973 Just iterate over your array and stop before you get to the 95th percentile of 20 (or whatever your map's size). Then you'll have the sum of the 95th percentile. Do you know how to iterate on a map?

Comment: Give me few minutes, I have started coding on this. I will update this thread with my solution and then let me know if I got it right or not.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I just wrote. let me know if the way I am doing is right or not? Thanks for the help.